# Speeding up a pattern matching algorithm in scala on a big csv file

Tags: database, performance, scala, csv

I'm currently trying to filter a large database using scala. I've written a simple piece of code to match an ID in one database to a list of ID's in another.

Essentially I want to go through database A and if the ID number in the ID column matches one from database B, to extract that entry from Database A.

The code i've written works fine, but it's slow (i.e. has to run over a couple of days) and i'm trying to find a way to speed it up. It may be that it can't be sped up by much, or it can be much much faster with better coding.

So any help would be much appreciated.

Below is a description of the databases and a copy of the code.

Database A is approximately 10gb in size with over 100 million entries and database B has a list of approx 50,000 IDs.

Each database looks like as follows:

```
Database A:
ID, DataX, date
10, 100,01012000
15, 20, 01012008
5, 32, 01012006
etc...

Database B:
ID
10
15
12
etc...
```

My code is as follows:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._

object filter extends App {

def ext[T <: Closeable, R](resource: T)(block: T => R): R = {
try { block(resource) }
finally { resource.close() }
}

val key = io.Source.fromFile("C:\\~Database_B.csv").getLines()
val key2 = new Array[String](50000)
key.copyToArray(key2)

ext(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\~Output.csv")))) {
writer =>
  val line = io.Source.fromFile("C:\\~Database_A.csv").getLines.drop(1)

  while (line.hasNext) {
    val data= line.next
    val array = data.split(",").map(_.trim)
    val idA = array(0)
    val dataX = array(1)
    val date = array(2)
    key2.map { idB =>
      if (idA == idB) {
        val print = (idA + "," + dataX + "," + date)
        writer.write(print)
        writer.newLine()
      } else None
    }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: You don't need variables `dataX` and `data`, just `writer.write(s"$data\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._

object filter extends App {

  def ext[T <: Closeable, R](resource: T)(block: T => R): R = {
    try { block(resource) }
    finally { resource.close() }
  }

  // convert to a Set
  val key2 = io.Source.fromFile("C:\\~Database_B.csv").getLines().toSet

  ext(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\~Output.csv")))) {
    writer =>
    val lines = io.Source.fromFile("C:\\~Database_A.csv").getLines.drop(1)
    for (data <- lines) {
      val array = data.split(",").map(_.trim)
      array match {
        case Array(idA, dataX, date) =>
          if (key2.contains(idA)) {
            val print = (idA + "," + dataX + "," + date)
            writer.write(print)
            writer.newLine()
          }
        case _ => // invalid input
      }
    }
  }
}
```

IDs are now stored in a set. This will give a better performance.

Answer (score 3):

First, there are way more efficient ways to do that than writing a Scala program. Loading two tables in a database and do a join will take about 10 minutes (including data loading) on a modern computer.

Assuming you have to use scala, there is an obvious improvement. Store you keys as a HashSet and use `keys.contains(x)` instead of traversing all keys. This would give you O(1) lookup instead of O(N) that you have now, which should speed up your program significantly.

Minor point -- use string interpolation instead of concatenation, i.e.

```
s"$idA,$dataX,$date"
// instead of
idA + "," + dataX + "," + date
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful suggestions, the use of a HashSet has speeded things up a fair amount.